# From keyword is define but I still get error

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to understand this type of error but I couldn't.

> ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
> 00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
> *Cause:
> *Action:
> Error at Line: 1 Column: 9

So far here is my query which I try to execute but I get error. As I see here I have `FROM` keyword as well as structure are correct If I am right.

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) 
     FROM project_plans PS1 
     WHERE PS1.Parent = PS.ProjectPlanID) AS children 
FROM 
    project_plans PS  
WHERE 
    PS.Parent = 23 AND PS.ProjectID = 141 
ORDER BY 
    Sort
```

What is wrong with this query? Where did I make a mistake?

So far I checked this post here:

[ORA-00923 From keyword not found where expected](https://www.tekstream.com/resource-center/ora-00923-from-keyword-not-found-where-expected/#:%7E:text=ORA%2D00923%20occurs%20when%20you,%2C%20misplaced%2C%20or%20altogether%20missing.)

Comment: You are missing alias of project_plans . you should use ps.* to run query.

Comment: No, It's not. I have alredy tried.

Comment: Row 1 column 9 is pointing this position and I can see only issue here is PS.* need to write.

Comment: As I sad before, I have alredy try this solution but still have same error 
https://imgur.com/8iudOqA

Comment: Attention to details , User Dot between ps and *. :)

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only missing alias name with * Add that into your query.
Order by should have that alias as well It will create problem in future

Modified Query should look like this

```
SELECT 
    PS.*, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) 
     FROM project_plans PS1 
     WHERE PS1.Parent = PS.ProjectPlanID) AS children 
FROM 
    project_plans PS  
WHERE 
    PS.Parent = 23 AND PS.ProjectID = 141 
ORDER BY 
    PS.Sort
```